# SQL query - I don't know all identifiers

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a way, where I can see every parameter or identifier I can query from my database? Not the contents but the "column names"

Something like

```
SELECT * FROM myDb AS String
```

Comment: Could you please be more specific? If database contains 1000 tables what do you want to see?

Comment: All attributes/parameters that are used in the Database(I only have access trough a query), e.g. If its a customerDb to show me what attributes are used like: customer_name, customer_address (I don't want the input, I want the "column names"

Comment: You may retrieve this data from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` table. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-schema-columns-table.html

Comment: You have it all here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-schema.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simply get the column names and types of a table.
You could [SHOW](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-columns.html) them.

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM myTable;
```

But if you want to know the column names of your table, and only a bit of data from it (to see what it looks like).

Then use LIMIT to get only a few records.

```
SELECT * 
FROM myTable
LIMIT 3
```

It's fast and easy.

But you can also just see the columns without data if you use a criteria that's false.

```
SELECT * 
FROM myTable
WHERE 0=1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use:

```
show create table table_name;
```

but as "LukStorms" mentioned, the below statement shows you the data in table format and in a pretier way

```
show columns from table_name;
```

Comment: I like this one. Getting the full create statement might be a bit to technical for most users, but it's easier than using the system views.

Answer (score 0):

You can use INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS to retrieve all columns name

> 

select column_name from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where Table_Name='Your_Table'